# Event handler for dynamically created Listbox control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Got a tough one here.

I am passing some values from a Gridview Update Click event to a popup ASP.net page that dynamically builds a series of textboxes in a Placeholder based on the number of sentences that are found in a specific cell of the Grid Row selected.

The boxes that are built represent each sentence found in the cell of the selected row. Each sentence is presented for translation, where user enters data into a 2nd dynamically generated textbox.

This all works great.

Now I have a Listbox beside the 2nd textbox, which sometimes has 1 or more variables that need to placed into the translated sentence. I have set up a Hover menu over the listbox so that I can select the variable and insert it at the end of the sentence in the 2nd textbox.

My problem is generating the click event on the dynamically created Listbox. Something like....

```
Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & ListBox1.SelectedValue
  ListBox1.SelectedValue = Nothing
End Sub
```

But recall my Listbox and other textboxes are all completely dynamically built with this code, where num is the number of sentences found in the original gridview row...

```
 Dim num As Integer = Session("lineNums") ' Number of sentences from original Gridview.
 Dim MainContent As ContentPlaceHolder = CType(Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"), ContentPlaceHolder)

 Dim ph As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(MainContent.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder)

 For I = 1 To num

  ' ***************************************************
  ' * Build English Header
    Dim txtD As New TextBox
    txtD.ID = "txtDEdit" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(txtD)

    Dim litCtrlD As New Literal
    litCtrlD.ID = "litCtrlD" & I.ToString("D2")
    litCtrlD.Text = "<br />"
    ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlD)
    txtD.Text = "ENGLISH"

  ' ***************************************************
  ' * Build English Textbox
    Dim txtA As New TextBox
    txtA.ID = "txtAEdit" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(txtA)

    Dim litCtrla As New Literal
    litCtrla.ID = "litCtrla" & I.ToString("D2")
    litCtrla.Text = "<br />"
    ph.Controls.Add(litCtrla)

  ' ***************************************************
  ' * Build Translator Header
    Dim txtE As New TextBox
    txtE.ID = "txtEEdit" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(txtE)

    Dim litCtrlE As New Literal
    litCtrlE.ID = "litCtrlE" & I.ToString("D2")
    litCtrlE.Text = "<br />"
    ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlE)

    txtE.Text = "TRANSLATION"

  ' ***************************************************
  ' * Build Translator Textbox
    Dim txtB As New TextBox
    txtB.ID = "txtBEdit" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(txtB)

    Dim litCtrl As New Literal
    litCtrl.ID = "litCtrl" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(litCtrl)

  ' ******************************
  ' *  Variable selection box
    Dim lstF As New ListBox
    lstF.ID = "lstFEdit" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(lstF)

    Dim litCtrlF As New Literal
    litCtrlF.ID = "litCtrlF" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlF)

  ' ******************************
  ' *  Hover Control Variable selection box
    Dim lstG As New ListBox
    lstG.ID = "lstGEdit" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(lstG)

    Dim litCtrlG As New Literal
    litCtrlG.ID = "litCtrlG" & I.ToString("D2")
    ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlG)

 Next I
```

I'm trying to execute Click Event of the dynamically built lstG Listbox control. And populate the dynamically built texbox control txtB.

thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [AddHandler statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

There you define what event you want to handle and the delegate(the method that handles this event, must have the correct signature).

So for your ListBox i assume that you want to handle the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindexchanged.aspx)-Event:

```
AddHandler lstG.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lstGChanged
```

And an appropriate handler somewhere in this class:

```
Private Sub lstGChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim triggeredFrom As ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
End Sub
```

And for your TextBox:

```
AddHandler txtA.TextChanged, AddressOf txtAChanged
```

And the handler:

```
Private Sub txtAChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim triggeredFrom As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure where to place the AddHandler lines of code for each control.

Comment: @Marc: Right there where you are creating them.

Comment: Do I need to do this in the Page Init Event, or the Page Load, I create the controls in both places so that I can persist view state.

Comment: I have it working but it requires a postback. I need to fire the post back on the click event in the listbox. any ideas? Okay I found that and have it firing now trying to populate the textbox.

Comment: I got it thanks for your help @Tim Still have some issues as my control(s) are created in a loop depending on the number of elements in the record. But I think I can figure that out. I added a Hover Menu but it only appears on the first control, need to create it dynamically as well.

Comment: @marc: Add another question for this issue since it's not directly related to this.